# Bash exceute multuple commands after || if non 0

Tags: bash, shell

I have a line of code in my scripts to make sure a conda environment exists and then if not install the environment and download the database for a programme in the environment. I have this code:

```
   test -d ~/miniconda3/envs/antismash_v5 || echo "Conda environment does not exist. Initialising conda environment......" && conda env create -f antismash.yml &&  conda activate antismash_v5 && download-antismash-databases
```

But this just exceute everything after the first `&&` regardless of if the `test` function returns non zero before `||`. How can I get this to work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `a || b && c` it first evaluates `a`:

- if `a` returns nonzero, it evaluates `b` and if `b` returns 0 it evaluates `c`
- if `a` returns 0, it ignores `b` and evaluates `c`

This operation is very similar to how boolean expressions are evaluated in C with the `&&` and `||` operator, except that unlike C, there is no operator precedence of `&&` over `||`.

Just like C, you can to use parentheses to make sure the condition is limited to the block of your choice, e.g.:

`a || (b && c)`

You could do something like that in your example:

```sh
test -d ~/miniconda3/envs/antismash_v5 ||
 (echo "Conda environment does not exist. Initialising conda environment......" &&
  conda env create -f antismash.yml &&
  conda activate antismash_v5 &&
  download-antismash-databases)
```

I have put the code on several lines for clarity but this can be done in one line.

Also, as @picklerick pointed out, parentheses will create a subshell. In your case it should not make a difference, but should you need to call your commands in the same shell, just use curly braces instead.

```sh
test -d ~/miniconda3/envs/antismash_v5 ||
 { echo "Conda environment does not exist. Initialising conda environment......" &&
  conda env create -f antismash.yml &&
  conda activate antismash_v5 &&
  download-antismash-databases;}
```

You need to use a whitespace after `{`.
You need to use a semicolon before `}` if you want to write it in one line.

Comment: worth noting that using `()` uses a subshell, whereas the above `{ ; }` executes in the current shell

Comment: @picklerick That’s right but since his commands are not making use of the current shell (e.g. assigning variables or sourcing files) I guess the result will be identical.

Comment: @picklerick yup, I was editing that at the same time you wrote your comment.

Comment: @picklerick that's what I wrote :)

Comment: Thank you for this. I am getting a syntax error though : `syntax error near unexpected token }`. Secondly if there a way to add a statsment that if  || exists with 0 the do `echo "environment exists"`

Comment: @Lamma I forgot to mention that you need a whitespace between `{` and `echo`. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Lamma You can do an if-then-else statement like this: `test -t ... && echo found || echo not found`. (you can then use parentheses/curly braces to replace `echo found` and `echo not found`). The conditions must be in this exact order. If you call `test -t ... || echo not found && echo found` it will not do what you want, for the very reason you had an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You can negate the `test` by using the bang `!` and enclose the rest of the commands inside an `if` statement, that way you don't need the `{ }`

```
if ! test -d ~/miniconda3/envs/antismash_v5; then
  command_here &&
  another_command_here &&
  some_more_commands_here &&
  do_more_commands here &&
  .....
fi
```

see `help test`

`help test | grep '^[[:blank:]]*!'`

output

`! EXPR         True if expr is false.`

Comment: is there an advantage of this method over the use of `{ }`?

Comment: Not so much of the advantage, you will get the same result in the end.  Unless you want to nest another `if` statement inside the `if` statement.  Just an old habit of mine that if I use `||` or `&&` I won't be mixing them together.

Comment: I prefer this form, on the grounds that it's much clearer what's going on -- both visually (`if` makes it clear this is a block of conditional code) and syntactically (`if` ... `fi` makes it clear what's conditional, with no potential ambiguities like you ran into with `||`).

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` have the same precedence, so you can wrap the following in `{}` eg. `... || { ... ; }`